# GNU GCC Compiler - Understanding alignment attribute in structures

Tags: c, gcc

I am having trouble understanding the aligned attribute in structures in C.

From the [gcc manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.3/gcc/Type-Attributes.html):

> This attribute specifies a minimum alignment (in bytes) for variables of the specified type. For example, the declarations:
>
> ```
>   struct S { short f[3]; } __attribute__ ((aligned (8)));
>   typedef int more_aligned_int __attribute__ ((aligned (8)));
> ```
>
> force the compiler to insure (as far as it can) that each variable
> whose type is struct S or more_aligned_int will be allocated and
> aligned at least on a 8-byte boundary.

From the above paragraph I understand that adding `__attribute__((aligned(x)))` to any kind of variable in C will force the compiler to assign a size of at least *x* bytes to the affected variable. For instance:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

uint8_t foo __attribute__((aligned(4)));

typedef struct {
  uint8_t x;
  uint32_t y;
  uint8_t z;
} __attribute__((aligned(8))) ex_struct_aligned_8_t;

int main(){

  printf("Data/Structure Sizes:\n");
  printf("  Aligned uint8_t Variable: %zu\n",sizeof(foo));
  printf("                 Aligned-8: %zu\n", sizeof(ex_struct_aligned_8_t));

  return 0;
}
```

From my understanding the output for `sizeof(foo)` should be 4 and the output for `sizeof(ex_struct_aligned_8_t)` should be 8. Summing up the size of each of the elements of the structure the total is 6 bytes, so the entire structure should fit perfectly with a memory alignment of 8 bytes. Nonetheless when the code is executed the printed values are 1 and 16 respectively.

Is there something I am missing here? Perhaps it is architecture related? I am running the code in a 64-bits operating system (Ubuntu 18.04) with gcc version 7.5.0.

Comment: For your `struct`, the `uint32_t` member has to be aligned to a 4-byte boundary, so the struct will not in fact fit in 8 bytes.  Maybe you're thinking the compiler should reorder the members to make it fit, but that is not allowed.

Comment: As you see, `aligned(N)` doesn't change the size of primitive types, though it does for aggregates (without alignment the size of your `struct` would be 12).  This causes a problem if you try to form an array of a primitive type with high alignment.  gcc rejects such code with an error, clang appears to accept it and silently ignore the alignment.

Comment: @NateEldredge so because of the `uint32_t` member in the `struct` having a size of 4 bytes, the other 2 members of type `uint8_t` are aligned in a 4-byte boundary for each making the total size of the structure 12 bytes? Is that why the output prints 16 bytes as the size of the structure (because the size has to be a multiple of 8 bytes)?

Comment: Just count it out.  `x` has to go at offset 0 in the struct, and occupies 1 byte.  `y` has to come next and its offset has to be a multiple of 4, so we insert 3 bytes of padding.  Then `y` goes at offset 4 and occupies 4 bytes.  `z` comes next, it goes at offset 8.  Now the struct would be 9 bytes, but its size has to be a multiple of its alignment, so padding is added to bring it up to 12 (without `__attribute__((aligned(8)))` or 16 (with it).

Comment: Now `z` was not required to be aligned to 4 bytes, it just so happened that it was.  But if you add `uint8_t zz;` after it in the struct, you'll find that the size is still 12 or 16 respectively, and that `zz` is not aligned at all, because there's no need for it to be.

Comment: In short, adding the sizes of the members is not a good way to guess the size of a struct.  Instead you have to think of building it up one element at a time, always respecting ordering and alignment.  This does mean that the same elements in a different order may result in the struct having a different size.  (Smallest to largest will always minimize that size.)

Comment: Thanks for the very clear explanation @NateEldredge! Now, concerning `foo`, is that also the reason why its size is 1 instead of 4? Because there is no padding needed considering that it is 1 byte long? If that's the case, then the `aligned(4)` command is being completely ignored, right?

Comment: No, it isn't being ignored.  You can be assured that the address of `foo` will be a multiple of 4.  But its size is still 1, and the compiler is free to store some other variable (not requiring alignment) in the very next byte. Your assumption that the compiler will "assign a size of at least x bytes to the affected variable" is simply incorrect for primitive types.

Comment: Crystal clear Nate! Thanks for your inmense help, it clarified all my doubts